# Some autocompletion doesn't work in Visual Studio Code with Unity

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio-code

I am using Unity 2018 with Visual Studio Code version 1.43.2 on a Mac.

---

Things seemed to work fine between Unity and Visual Studio Code, but now I realize that something is wrong with Code. I have been following along with a tutorial and the autocompletion functionality of Code seemed fine until the function `OnTriggerEnter`, which was shown as autocompleting for the guy in the video (who was using the *other* Visual Studio), didn't fill in. However, many other Unity things do automatically show up as options.

I looked at [this Microsoft help page about VS Code and Unity](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), and I have everything it I seems I would possibly need to combine the two; I have .NET, Mono, [Debugger for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug), the C# extension, and got [Unity Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools) for good measure.

Generic C# things like `return`, `void`, `int`, etc. autocomplete, so the C# extension seems fine. Many Unity things, like `Vector3`, `GameObject`, `Destroy`, `transform`, etc. also autocomplete like they should.

**What is wrong here? How can I fix this and get full autocomplete?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is `Vector3`, `GameObject`, `Destroy` are all staticly typed classes or methods inside classes. Thus intellisense can autocomplete them.

On the other hand, `Awake`, `Start`, `Update` and other 'unity callbacks' are not. What Unity engine does it uses reflection, to check if the `MonoBehaviour` has any of those 'callbacks' in it (through name (as string) reference). If it does, the callback gets called. Because there's no staticly typed method as `Awake`, `Start`, etc., intellisense cannot autocomplete it.

As for solution, there are extensions, can't remember names exatcly, that add snippets for `Start`, `Update` and other callbacks.

Comment: What's strange here is that the video OP was watching apparently showed this MonoBehaviour message method autocompleting, though I've never observed that in my own use of Unity & VS. It's possible the creator of the tutorial had set up a superclass or interface that defined this method, [though this comes with pitfalls](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/), or was using some additional extension not listed here.

Comment: +1 for useful reference link. It explains pretty much everything. 

Comment: Thanks! Based on your suggestion I got [Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets) which adds autocomplete for this stuff.